# Xcode 11 debug variables view doesn't show class variables

Tags: ios, swift, xcode11

When paused at a breakpoint you see the list of variables in the lower-left debug window. With Xcode 11 `self` no longer provides access to the class variables. Prior to Xcode 10 you could hover over a class variable in the Editor and see its value. That feature disappeared in Xcode 10 - you had to expand the `self` variable. Now you can't even do that.

Am I missing something basic here? Am I forced to use `po` commands in lldb?

Answer (score 2):

At the time you’re hovering over the type properties, has your app accessed it yet? Type properties are instantiated lazily, so if you haven’t accessed it yet, it won’t yet be initialized. As [The Swift Programming Language: Properties](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID264) says:

> Stored type properties are lazily initialized on their first access. They are guaranteed to be initialized only once, even when accessed by multiple threads simultaneously, and they do not need to be marked with the lazy modifier.

For example, in Xcode 11.0 (11A420a) this is right before I access that property the first time:

[image]

It hasn’t been initialized yet, so I don’t see any value associated with that property. But after I access that type property, I will then see the property initialized:

[image]

Or, now that I’ve accessed it, I can also now hover over the property in my code and also see that it’s now initialized:

[image]

Or, if you’re in a method of that class, you’ll now see the type property listed in the “Variables” section of the “Debug” panel (again, only after your code references it the first time and it is initialized lazily):

[image]

Comment: Consider this code: 'import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  var test = false

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let x = 3
    print("x = \\(x)")
    print("test = \\(test)")
  }
}
'  Break on the print("test =") line. Hovering over test in \(test) doesn't do anything. In my primary project I can't even see "test" in the debug-variable window under 'self'. I can in this simple example. Why?

Comment: First, I have to apologize because when you said “class variables” , I thought you were talking about “type properties” (because what was called a “class property” in Objective-C is called a “type property” in Swift). But it appears that you’re talking about “instance properties”. Second, yes, I see the same behavior you do, that I don’t see the “hover over” behavior for instance properties (though I see it in the debug panel and if I have `self.test`, I can hover over `self`, twizzle that open, and see my instance properties there). ...

Comment: ... Third, I don’t know why the behavior is different in your project versus your test project and it’s hard to help without reproducible example of the problem. Try creating blank project, keep adding stuff from your real project, periodically checking the behavior, and see if you can see what you have to add to manifest the behavior in question. But the problem is either some setting in your project (e.g. optimized build), setting in your IDE (e.g. the debug panel set for “auto” vs “local”), or just some inexplicable compiler/IDE issue. Hard to say until we can reproduce.

Comment: Rob, You have no need to apologize for my confusing/unclear use of terminology! I should apologize. Sorry. So is there any kind of setting that would control the hover behavior of instance properties? Does Apple intend some other mechanism be used? Does this appear to be a bug in Xcode? I'll have to work on building up a project that duplicates the debug panel issue